# strange speedup in kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency

I have these two kotlin code snippets for measuring the startup times of threads.

First:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() {
 runBlocking {
     for(i in 0..99){
        val start = System.nanoTime()
           launch {
               val time = System.nanoTime() - start
               println("Starttime: %,d".format(time))
          }
       }
    }
  }
```

This code starts by printing something in the range of 35.000.000, and goes through 100iterations where the value becomes larger and ends around 75.000.000.
Now if I run this code

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() {
     runBlocking {
         val list:MutableList<Long> = MutableList<Long>(100, {0})
         for(i in 0..99){
             val start = System.nanoTime()
             launch {
                   list[i] = System.nanoTime() - start
                 }
      }
    delay(1000) // wait for all coroutines to have stored result
    list.forEach{ println("Starttime: %,d".format(it)) }
 }
}
```

This code is obviously faster, since the print statement is not included in the launch. But there is some other behaviour which is strange. It starts around 50.000.000, jumps directly to 17.083.000, and then slowly climbs back up to 29.507.300 where it ends.

So my questions is: why does the first piece of code deteriorate so fast, and quickly become slow, while the second code is able to be so much faster, and that it doesnt become slower over time as i add more coroutines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a little mistake of not preloading classes before measuring time so results are skewed. You should also print jobs index so you can see in what order jobs are actually completed.

I'd suggest modifying your code samples:

First:

```
suspend fun main() {
    // dummy calls to preload classes before measuring
    val s = System.nanoTime()
    GlobalScope.launch { println("starting %,d".format(s)) }.join()

    repeat(100) { i ->
        val start = System.nanoTime()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val time = System.nanoTime() - start
            println("Starttime[$i]: %,d".format(time))
        }
    }
    delay(1000) // wait for all coroutines to print result
}
```

Second:

```
suspend fun main() {
    // dummy calls to preload classes before measuring
    val s = System.nanoTime()
    GlobalScope.launch { println("starting %,d".format(s)) }.join()

    val list: MutableList<Long> = MutableList<Long>(100, { 0 })
    repeat(100) { i ->
        val start = System.nanoTime()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            list[i] = System.nanoTime() - start
        }
    }
    delay(1000) // wait for all coroutines to have stored result
    list.forEachIndexed { i, it -> println("Starttime[$i]: %,d".format(it)) }
}
```

First sample obviously "deteriorates" as you just pile up 100 jobs instantly while they take significant amount of time to access `System.out` to perform printing operation. You may also experience they most likely do not print [their index] in order.

Second sample is more or less stable because jobs don't perform any heavy operations so there's usually a free thread in `Dispatchers.Default` pool to execute launch block immediately.

Comment: thanks! but when im not specifying a dispatcher, isnt the whole thing just running on the main thread?

Comment: @n00bster no, [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) uses `Dispatchers.Default` by default. Running on main thread would make no sense as it'd just block.

Comment: hmm, but if i include a print of Thread.currentThread in my print, the launch without any dispatcher will say mainthread, while Dispatchers.default will alternate between threads?

Comment: If you're using `launch` as a child of `runBlocking` it inherits its coroutine context so it will indeed execute in a blocking fashion.

Comment: ok, so in my example, dispatchers.default is not the same as running without a explicit dispatcher?